# Mediawiki add rel "nofollow" in anchor tag of every Header of Template Page

Tags: php, mediawiki

```
 <a title="Template:CompanyProfile" href="/wikiinvestor  /index.php?title=Template:CompanyProfile&amp;action=edit&amp;section=T-1">edit</a>
```

and i want to create like

```
<a title="Template:CompanyProfile" rel="nofollow" href="/wikiinvestor/index.php?title=Template:CompanyProfile&amp;action=edit&amp;section=T-1">edit</a>
```

it's possible using Skin.php file of mediawiki software. and if possible then how to done that please give me answer.

Comment: What link are you referring to exactly? What do you mean by “Header of Template page”?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what link you are referring to. As for the page content, MediaWiki by default adds `nofollow` to all external links, but no internal. If you want to add custom attributes to internal links (e.g. if you are referring to a link in a template in your question) , you can use one of the extensions [LinkAttributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLinkAttributes) or [Link Attributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLink_Attributes) (easily confused names, yes).

If you are talking about a link printed out by the skin (I cant' figure out which one that would be from your question, but you are talking about Skin.php, so I guess that might be the case), e.g. “edit”, “history”, etc, or something in the toolbox, your best option is to write your own extension, using the appropriate hook (see [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks) for a full list). All built in skins will execute all of the skin related hooks, though some custom made ones might not.